# Wrong column type - Found: serial, expected: int8

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, grails

I'm writing my first Grails app and I've reversed my existing Postgresql schema using the Grails Application Generator.  (GRAG)  When I run the app, I get the error:

> Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.HibernateException:  Wrong column type in
>   public.event_staff for column event_staff_id. Found: serial, expected:
>   int8

I'm guessing this is due to "serial" not being a *real* type in Postgresql and more of an alias for an auto incrementing integer value that is tied to a sequence.  I imagine there is a clean way to work around this issue, but having no experience with Hibernate I'm not sure the best way to move forward.

Here's the class in question:

```
 class EventStaff {
        static mapping = {
             table 'event_staff'
             // version is set to false, because this 
             // isn't available by default for legacy databases
             version false
             id generator:'identity', column:'event_staff_id', name: 'eventStaffId'
             staffMemberIdStaffMember column:'staff_member_id'
             gameIdGame column:'game_id'
        }

        Long eventStaffId
        Boolean shouldNotify
        Date created
        Date modified
        // Relation
        StaffMember staffMemberIdStaffMember
        // Relation
        Game gameIdGame

        static constraints = {
            eventStaffId()
            shouldNotify()
            created()
            modified()
            staffMemberIdStaffMember()
            gameIdGame()
        }

        String toString() {
            return "${eventStaffId}" 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hibernate is not being able to convert 'serial' to a valid Java type. It's kind of an [old problem](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-6179). If you can, change your database id type to bigint or bigserial instead of serial, like [this guy](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=993712) did, it will probably solve your problem. If not, try specifying the type of the column with:

```
id generator:'identity', column:'event_staff_id', 
name: 'eventStaffId', type: 'serial' //though I don't know if 'serial' will work in this dialect.
```

Still you can try to change your id type to Integer instead of Long.

Try these tips separately.

Comment: Thanks.  It ended up being that I needed to change my class member eventStaffId to Integer from Long.

Comment: I also needed to change datatype from Long to Integer. Thanks